# Reading data file, structure of data obtained with GDB from an elf file

Tags: c++, struct, gdb

I have a data file "tasks.data" from a game, and I want to read it.

from an ELF FILE from the game "tasks.so" I got the data structure using GDB, gdb ptype etc

I am reading the file without problems getting the fields correctly until I find some vector types that I think I am not reading correctly.

part of the structure from gdb:

```
..etc...
....
bool m_bOnFailPopup;
unsigned int m_ulOnFailSoundID;
unsigned int m_ulOnFailGfxID;
unsigned int m_ulNextSibling;
unsigned int m_ulFirstChild;
std::wstring m_wstrName;
std::wstring m_wstrNameSuffix;
std::wstring m_wstrDescript;
std::wstring m_wstrOnNewTribute;
std::wstring m_wstrOnNewConfirm;
std::wstring m_wstrOnCompleteConfirm;
std::wstring m_wstrMethodTrace;
std::wstring m_wstrMethodString;
std::wstring m_wstrCategory;
std::wstring m_wstrUnitProtectWarning;
std::wstring m_wstrUnitProtectFailed;
talk_proc m_DelvTaskTalk;
talk_proc m_AwardTalk;

//until here I can read without problems, I read the bytes and get the data

//here are this others vector things that I not sure I am reading correctly

std::vector<TaskSimpleCondition, std::allocator<TaskSimpleCondition> > m_vetPremSimple;
std::vector<TASK_OPEN_TIME, std::allocator<TASK_OPEN_TIME> > m_vetOpenTime;
std::vector<ITEM_WANTED, std::allocator<ITEM_WANTED> > m_vetPremItems;
std::vector<short, std::allocator<short> > m_vetPremTitles;
std::vector<REPU_WANT, std::allocator<REPU_WANT> > m_vetPremRepu;
```

I am using python for this, I read the file go to the offset where this data starts, and read bytes show int or decode text of it is a string.
The struct I have from GDB is parsed inside python, not used as a class or anything. I parse each line of the struct, get varname, vartype and read bytes according to what it is.

For example, if it is "bool varname" I read 1 byte and get the int and continue to the next structure line.

Whith those std::vector lines I am doing the same:

example

```
std::vector<TaskSimpleCondition, std::allocator<TaskSimpleCondition> > m_vetPremSimple;
```

which I am reading as if it where:

```
TaskSimpleCondition m_vetPremSimple;
```

I get the struct of "TaskSimpleCondition" and for each line of that I read its bytes.

the thing is below that line I start to get funky data, so Probably I am reading it wrong.

So the main question is: how should I treat the std::vector lines? is that vector an internal thing of the library and has nothing to do the the data read from the data.file ?

Also at the end of the main struct which its name is (ATaskTempl) I have this lines, which I am ignoring for the moment

```
...etc...
ATaskTempl *m_pParent;
ATaskTempl *m_pPrevSibling;
ATaskTempl *m_pNextSibling;
ATaskTempl *m_pFirstChild;)
```

because it would cause an infinite loop, it would get struct of ATaskTempl at the end another child var would get the same struct, and so on.

Can someone guide me in this?

I am writing this in python, the struct I am using it is from an ELF file read with GDB.

One last thing, I have some structs that say:

```
type = struct CLASSNAME : ANOTHER_CLASSNAME {
    data.....
```

What I am doing in those cases is getting the second class struct, and adding the first class struct. is that correct?

Comment: Vectors are not simple types. Not only do they use dynamically allocated memory, even if you just wanted the basic part of the class, unless you use the exact same stl version that was previously used you’re asking for ub. As the layout could change.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a data file "tasks.data" from a game, and I want to read it.

To do this, you need to know *how* the data was stored.

> from the game "tasks.so" I got the data structure using GDB

It is *exceedingly unlikely* that the structure you got is what is actually saved on disk (it may well be used to represent data *in memory*, but it simply *can't* represent the data *on disk*).

The structure contains `std::wstring`s which will contain a pointer to data instead of actual data (at least for long enough strings).

It also contains `std::vector`s, which *always* contain pointers instead of actual data.

> For example, if it is "bool varname" I read 1 byte and get the int and continue to the next structure line.

This would also be incorrect, unless the structure has `__attribute__((packed))` -- there should be a padding gap between a `bool` and the following `int`.

> So the main question is: how should I treat the std::vector lines?

You will have to reverse-engineer the `tasks.so` library to understand *how* it stores the `std::vector`s on disk, and then apply reverse transformation to restore in-memory view from on-disk view.

Here is one way that a vector could be stored on disk (but not necessarily the way `tasks.so` does it):

```
// returns number of bytes stored, or -1 on error.
ssize_t save_vec(const std::vector<short>& v, FILE *out)
{
  const size_t size = v.size();
  if (1 != fwrite(&size, sizeof(size_t), 1, out)) return -1;
  if (size != fwrite(v.data(), sizeof(v[0]), size, out)) return -1;
  return sizeof(size) + size * sizeof(v[0]);
}
```

To reverse above transformation, you would (obviously) read the size, create a vector of appropriate size, and then read actual data into it.

Comment: thank for your anwser, I will try to read the libtask.so with ghidra or something to see if I can find the part where it reads the tasks.data file